# Java Spring Scheduler Stuck after a while

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, scheduler

I have scheduler which runs after every 1 minute, but after a while it got stuck without any error/logs. so took the thread dump using "kill -3 ".

In thread dump i found that Most of the threads were in WAITING(Parking)/(Sleeping) state.

So, How do i resolve this stuck issue.
Please help.

**My scheduler configuration is as following :**

```
 <bean id="ProcessPayloadScheduler" 
class="com.sfi.scheduler.ProcessPayloadScheduler"></bean>
    <task:scheduler id="processPayloadSchedulerTask" pool-size="10" />
    <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="processPayloadSchedulerTask">
        <task:scheduled ref="ProcessPayloadScheduler" method="processData" cron="0 0/1 * 1/1 * ?" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>
```

---

```
**Thread Dump is :** 

2017-05-24 07:40:04
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode):

"processPayloadSchedulerTask-10" #49 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f966845c000 nid=0xdc9b waiting on condition [0x00007f9636343000]
   **java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)**
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c10fabd8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"processPayloadSchedulerTask-9" #48 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f964c052800 nid=0xdc97 waiting on condition [0x00007f9636444000]
   **java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)**
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c10fabd8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"processPayloadSchedulerTask-8" #47 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9650094800 nid=0xdc93 waiting on condition [0x00007f9636545000]
   **java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)**
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c10fabd8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"processPayloadSchedulerTask-7" #46 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9640009000 nid=0xdc60 waiting on condition [0x00007f9636646000]
   **java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)**
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c10fabd8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"processPayloadSchedulerTask-6" #45 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9648002800 nid=0xdc5d runnable [0x00007f9636745000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:112)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:159)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:187)
    - locked <0x00000000c0d89c58> (a com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3158)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3615)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3604)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2832)
    - locked <0x00000000c0d7eb18> (a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2781)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1569)
    - locked <0x00000000c0d7eb18> (a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:658)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:635)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1165)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:474)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.sfi.scheduler.ProcessPayloadScheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$871a0ddd.processData(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"processPayloadSchedulerTask-5" #44 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f964c052000 nid=0xdbc6 waiting on condition [0x00007f9636848000]
   **java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)**
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c10fabd8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"processPayloadSchedulerTask-4" #43 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9640005000 nid=0xdbc2 waiting on condition [0x00007f9636949000]
   **java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)**
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c10fabd8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"processPayloadSchedulerTask-3" #42 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f964c1df800 nid=0xdbba waiting on condition [0x00007f9636a4a000]
   **java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)**
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c10fabd8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"http-nio-9090-exec-10" #41 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f96500a8000 nid=0xdb78 waiting on condition [0x00007f9636b4b000]
   **java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)**
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fcb91b10> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"processPayloadSchedulerTask-2" #40 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f964c1db800 nid=0xdb77 waiting on condition [0x00007f9636c4c000]
   **java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)**
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c10fabd8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"http-nio-9090-exec-9" #39 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9650038800 nid=0xdb76 waiting on condition [0x00007f9636e2e000]
   **java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)**
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fcb91b10> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"http-nio-9090-exec-8" #38 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9650098000 nid=0xdb75 waiting on condition [0x00007f9636f2f000]
   **java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)**
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fcb91b10> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f966806f800 nid=0xdb4e runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f966801d800 nid=0xdb4d runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f96680b2000 nid=0xdb55 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 340

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 295424K, used 182333K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 241664K, 72% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f5625aa0,0x00000000f9700000)
  from space 53760K, 13% used [0x00000000fcb80000,0x00000000fd269a80,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 53760K, 0% used [0x00000000f9700000,0x00000000f9700000,0x00000000fcb80000)
 ParOldGen       total 349696K, used 20886K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000d5580000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 349696K, 5% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c1465b58,0x00000000d5580000)
 Metaspace       used 45242K, capacity 46416K, committed 46592K, reserved 1089536K
  class space    used 5309K, capacity 5554K, committed 5632K, reserved 1048576K
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?